# Using ScheduledExecutorService to save(Entites), I get detached Entity passed to persist error

Tags: java, hibernate, entity, spring-data-jpa, scheduledexecutorservice

I have a very curious Error that I cant seem to get my head around.
I need to use a ScheduledExecutorService to pass the Survey Entity I created to be edited and then saved as a new Entity.

```
public void executeScheduled(Survey eventObject, long interval) {
    HashMap<String, String> eventRRules = StringUtils.extractSerialDetails(eventObject.getvCalendarRRule());

    long delay = 10000;

    ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        private int counter = 1;
        private int executions = Integer.parseInt(eventRRules.get("COUNT"));
        Survey survey = eventObject;
        public void run() {
            String uid = eventObject.getUniqueEventId();
            logger.info("SurveyController - executeScheduled - Iteration: " + counter);
            String serialUid = null;
            if (counter == 1) {
                serialUid = uid + "-" + counter;
            } else {
                serialUid = StringUtils.removeLastAndConcatVar(eventObject.getUniqueEventId(), Integer.toString(counter));
            }
            if (++counter > executions) {
                service.shutdown();
            }

            survey.setUniqueEventId(serialUid);
            try {
            executeCreateSurvey(survey);
            } catch(Exception e) {
                logger.debug("SurveyController - executeScheduled - Exception caught: ");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    service.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnable, delay, interval, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```

When the executeCreateSurvey(survey) Method is run without the ScheduleExecutorService, it works flawlessly.
Yet when it is executed inside the run() Method, I get the "detached entity passed to persist" Error each time the save(survey) Method is run within the executeCreateSurvey() Method....

The executeCreateSurvey() Method where the .save() Method is called:

```
public ResponseEntity<?> executeCreateSurvey(Survey eventObject) {
    MailService mailService = new MailService(applicationProperties);

    Participant eventOwner = participantRepositoryImpl.createOrFindParticipant(eventObject.getEventOwner());
    eventObject.setEventOwner(eventOwner);

    Survey survey = surveyRepositoryImpl.createSurveyOrFindSurvey((Survey) eventObject);

    // Saves additional information if small errors (content
    // errors,.. )
    // occurs
    String warnMessage = "";
    List<Participant> participants = new ArrayList<Participant>();
    for (Participant participantDetached : eventObject.getParticipants()) {

        // Check if participant already exists
        Participant participant = participantRepositoryImpl.createOrFindParticipant(participantDetached);
        participants.add(participant);

        // Only create PartSur if not existing (Update case)
        if (partSurRepository.findAllByParticipantAndSurvey(participant, survey).isEmpty()) {
            PartSur partSur = new PartSur(participant, survey);
            partSurRepository.save(partSur);

            try {
                mailService.sendRatingInvitationEmail(partSur);
                surveyRepository.save(survey);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // no special exception for "security" reasons
                String errorMessage = "error sending mail for participant: " + e.getMessage() + "\n";
                warnMessage += errorMessage;
                logger.warn("createSurvey() - " + errorMessage);
            }
        }
    }

    // Delete all PartSurs and Answers from removed participants
    List<PartSur> partSursForParticipantsRemoved = partSurRepository.findAllByParticipantNotIn(participants);
    logger.warn("createSurvey() - participants removed: " + partSursForParticipantsRemoved.size());
    partSurRepositoryImpl.invalidatePartSurs(partSursForParticipantsRemoved);

    return new ResponseEntity<>("Umfrage wurde angelegt. Warnungen: " + warnMessage, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

What could the reason be for this?
I have not been able to find this Problem anywhere so far.

Comment: which doesn't seem to have any calls to the JPA API in it ...

Comment: Like I said: The save(survey) method is called within the executeCreateSurvey() Method in the posted code...
"each time the save(survey) Method is run within the executeCreateSurvey() Method...."

Comment: and like I said, WE dont see any calls to the JPA API, and consequently cannot see what objects are passed in to them, or the lifecycle state they are in at calling them, and so on. So you need to debug your problem

Comment: Does the Edit help? I added the Method where the call is made.

Comment: doesn't help me because you aren't calling the JPA API. You seem to be using "Spring Data JPA" (!= JPA API). If so then fix the tags on your question to use `spring-data-jpa` instead of `jpa`